# How to duplicate a MySQL database on the same server

Tags: mysql, database, synchronization, replicate

I have a large MySQL database, lets call it `live_db`, which I want to replicate on the same machine to provide a test system to play around with (`test_db`), including table structure and data.
In regular intervals I want to update the `test_db` with the content of the `live_db`; if possible incremental.

Is there some built-in mechanism in MySQL to do that? I think that master-slave replication is not the thing I want since it should be possible to alter data in the `test_db`. These changes do not have to be preserved, though.

Regards,

CGD

Comment: 12.9 GB at the moment and growing.

Comment: In the unlikely case that you don't have `auto_increment` keys to worry about, you could set up replication, but keep the slave stopped most of the time.  Periodically then, you `START SLAVE;` and it brings itself up to date.  If you have any auto_increment fields though this will result in key collisions.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

The `mysql` command line client will accept a stream of SQL statements from standard input.  You can therefore pipe the output of `mysqldump` directly into `mysql` on the command line.  Doing this as a cron job will regularly overwrite your test data with updated live data:

```sh
mysql --user=username --password=passwd -e 'DROP DATABASE test_db;'
mysql --user=username --password=passwd -e 'CREATE DATABASE test_db;'
mysqldump --user=username --password=passwd live_db | mysql --user=username --password=passwd test_db
```

Note that since your data is large, it will take a long time.

Comment: This is the best way that I have found. I'll looking forward to hearing of a better way.

Comment: As I stated in the comment above the DB is currently 12.9 GB and growing. Doing a full dump takes an awful lot of time.

Comment: OK, I did it this way. Creating the dump is actually quite fast. Importing it, though, is a different matter. The whole process takes about 15 minutes which is not sooo bad... I also looked into mysqlhotcopy but decided against it. Thanks all!

Comment: Do you really need the DROP|CREATE databsae: mysqldump will include DROP TABLEs anyway, so unless you generate tables in the test db (which would therefore still be there unless manually DROPped), you don't need the first two lines?

Comment: I've used mysqldbcopy: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.3/en/mysqldbcopy.html

Comment: and there should be space between `-u` and `username`

Comment: @DarkSide Most platforms accept it without a space, certainly any *nix - does Windows not? Anyway, to avoid confusion with the password, the space is left out here.  The `-p` must _not_ have a space: _"The password of the MySQL account. As described earlier, the password value is optional, but if given, there must be no space between -p or --password= and the password following it. The default is to send no password."_ http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting.html

Comment: I'm not talking about `-p`, but about `-u`.

Comment: @DarkSide I understand you're talking about `-u`. I am trying to say that `-u` was deliberately presented without a space here to be consistent and avoid confusion with `-p`, since `-p` must not have a space. I am asking you to confirm that there is a platform or MySQL version that will _not_ correctly parse `-uusername` (Windows perhaps?), because I have not encountered one to my recollection.  Either way though I'll just change them both to the long form `--username,--password` above.

Comment: yey, looks that it's working with `-uusername` too! I take my workds (above) back then :)

Comment: Please note, do NOT use the --database orig_db parameter on the left-hand-side if you are wanting to restore to a different database.  mysqldump will include a "use `orig_db`;" statement in its output, and you'll not be writing to the db you specified on the right-hand-side of the pipe.  Learned that one the hard way. : - /

Comment: I do this and works fine, but when i want to open the database with other user it seems that doesn't copy all the permissions of the source database to the path database... any suggest? :/

Comment: Grants/permissions are not stored with the database so dumping the database won't include them. You must separately `SHOW GRANTS` and place its output into the new database http://serverfault.com/questions/8860/how-can-i-export-the-privileges-from-mysql-and-then-import-to-a-new-server

Comment: This is incredibly slow. Though I can mysqldump in about 1-2 seconds, it takes 35 minutes to import to the new db with mysql command line. What about `mysqldbcopy`? I haven't tried it yet but perhaps it's faster. What I'd really like to know if I can just copy a data folder for very fast copying.

Comment: @ButtleButkus 35 minutes is unusually & unreasonably slow. With extensive indexing, the load time would be significantly longer than the dump time, but not by 100x's of times. Do you have query logging enabled on the target server? Bin logs for replication? Anything else unusual? Try mysqldbcopy to see if it makes a difference for you. If not, I might suspect a problem with the filesystem on the target server.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski it's a large database. Some tables have 300,000 rows, a few even have millions of rows. Using mysql to import is slow because it runs all of these insert queries, right? My impression is that mysql is the bottleneck. But why even export and import, if it might be possible just to copy files in the file system? The server is CentOS 6 with a fast processor and 32GB RAM. Trying to load the same db on a local VM would take hours.

Comment: It is possible under some circumstances. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-migration.html#copy-tables-cold-backup also http://serverfault.com/questions/367255/linux-mysql-is-it-safe-to-copy-mysql-db-files-with-cp-command-from-one-db-to

Comment: MySQL provides for [incremental backups](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-enterprise-backup/4.1/en/mysqlbackup.incremental.html), which should make the transfers _much_ faster...

Answer (score 11):

Michaels answer abowe works well but does not copy events, stored procedures or triggers.

To copy those a few more switches is needed for mysqldump:
`--events --triggers --routines`

To complement an already made copy:

`mysqldump --user=username --password=passwd --no-data --no-create-info --no-create-db --events --triggers --routines live_db | mysql --user=username --password=passwd test_db`

Answer (score 5):

I have been doing this for several years in different contexts, with small to medium databases (1 G to 100 G). The quick and dirty `mysqldump` works for smaller data sets; the smaller they are, the better it goes.

When you exceed 5-10 GB, depending on the MySQL load, **quick and dirty** does not cut it anymore.

## why `mysqldump` might not be enough

The problem with MySQLdump is that while it dumps, the live database is either unusable, very awkward to use, or the backup will not be consistent. Unless you have a wide enough time window when the unusability of the live database is not important because the database needs not be in use anyway (for example, late at night).

The default options ([here](https://serversforhackers.com/c/mysqldump-with-modern-mysql) a discussion of the why) make the database next to unusable while it's being dumped, *unless* the usage is just reading data and little of that. On a busy ecommerce site, you're looking at a client pile-up crash.

So you use InnoDB and the modern options (not defaults, as far as I know)

```
--single-transaction --skip-lock-tables
```

which allow the site to run, albeit slower than normal, during the dump. Depending on what the usage is, it might be **noticeably** slower.

While you're at it, also dump other data which might be important:

```
--events --triggers --routines
```

(...oh, and this still won't have dumped user permissions. To use as a test perhaps it wasn't so important).

There is a workaround I've found "advised" (!) as a "great hack", which basically **disables transactional integrity** allowing the database to run at full speed while it's being dumped. Somewhat like removing the brakes from your car to lighten it and have it run faster, yeah it will work, but it'll have some side effects that you might not notice immediately. You *will* almost surely notice them sooner or later - and just like brakes, it will be when you'll need them most, and it won't be pretty.

However, for a *test* database, it could still work.

## Xtrabackup

If you have a "serious" database, what's the reason not to have [a "serious" backup](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.4/intro.html)?

## Slave replication

Another possibility if you have space to spare - and, nowadays, 20 Gb is not that much - is that of using an ancillary database.

You can install *a second copy of MySQL Server* on the same server on a different port, and have it be the slave (the server will take a performance hit, storage-speed-wise). Then you will have two identical databases (live master, live slave). **The first time** you will still have to run a full dump to get them in sync, with all the problems it involves.

When you need to clone the test database, stop the slave replication - the live slave will now remain "frozen" in time - and backup the live slave to the test db, using MySQLbackup or just copying the data files. Once done, you restart the replication.

The impact on the live master is negligible, and the slave can actually be used for non-update-critical selects.

Answer (score 0):

In case you prefer MySQL Migration Toolkit, you may double click on schema name in Data Mapping step and change target schema name.

Answer (score 0):

For all the mac users, with sequel pro all you need to do is go to database (menu) -> Duplicate database. Done!